# Create/populate a csv file with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am having a little trouble creating/populating a csv file with powershell. I am new to powershell, so I may be missing some obvious things, so please go easy on me. Here is the situation:

First I am creating an array(?) to act as my table

```
#Create output table with headers
$output = @()
$row = New-Object System.Object
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Example Header 1" -Value $null
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Example Header 2" -Value $null
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Example Header 3" -Value $null
$output += $row
```

I am writing it to a file using
`$output | Export-Csv new.csv -NoTypeInformation`

This appears to make a csv file with the headers that I want. If there is a better way to do this, please let me know. The next step is where I am running into problems. I now need to programatically populate the table with data. When importing existing csv files, I am able to access/modify data in the table like an array (i.e. `$output[rowIndex]."Header Name" = "new data"`).

So I tried to add data to my newly created table. I wrote `$ouput[0]."Example Header 1" = "Test Data"`. This works as I expected and populates the first row in the column with the specified header with "Test Data". However, I can ONLY access [0]. `$output[1]` and so on cause errors because I guess they do not exist. I tried using `$output += $row` again to add more rows, but it does not work at all and causes some strange errors to happen (if I write to a row, it writes to all rows, probably because its all the same object).

So basically my question is, **how can I create a csv file from scratch, add some headers to it, and then start writing to all the (unknown/variable number of) rows**? I am sure there is a better way to do it, but like I said, I am very new to powershell. Ideally I would like to be able to access rows by index (0,1,2, etc) but I am open to whatever.

---

**Basic solution** (adapted from [Martin Brandl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44113932/45375))

This basically reads data from one csv file, and inserts it into another with new specified headers.

```
$csv = Import-Csv "MyCsv.csv"
$newCsv = @()
foreach($row in $csv) {
    $newCsv += [PSCustomObject]@{
        "New Column Header1" = $row."Original Column Header1"
        "New Column Header2" = $row."Original Column Header2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't write headers and data as separate manual steps. Create an array of objects representing each row, and then pipe all of it `Export-Csv` at once, it'll automatically extract property names and create the header row for you. Show us the input CSV samples + desired output format if you want help with rewriting existing CSV data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [Mathias mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113740/create-populate-a-csv-file-with-powershell/44113932#comment75246925_44113740), you shouldn't create the CSV first containg only the headers. Instead, populate your CSV with the actual rows you want and *export* it:

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    'Example Header 1' = "a"
    'Example Header 2' = "b"
    'Example Header 3' = "c"
}, [PSCustomObject]@{
    'Example Header 1' = "a2"
    'Example Header 2' = "b2"
    'Example Header 3' = "c2"
}, [PSCustomObject]@{
    'Example Header 1' = "a3"
    'Example Header 2' = "b4"
    'Example Header 3' = "c5"
} | Export-Csv new.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Output:**

```
"Example Header 1","Example Header 2","Example Header 3"
"a","b","c"
"a2","b2","c2"
"a3","b4","c5"
```

Answer (score 13):

To complement [Martin Brandl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44113932/45375) with an **explanation of your symptoms** (emphasis added):

> I tried using `$output += $row` again to add more rows, but it does not work at all and causes some strange errors to happen (if I write to a row, it writes to all rows, **probably because it's all the same object**).

Indeed, that is what happened: In .NET terms, type (class) **`[pscustomobject]` is a *reference type* rather than a *value type*** - as evidenced by `[pscustomobject].IsValueType` returning `$false`.

If you **add a given instance (object) of a reference type** to an array ***multiple* times, all such elements point to the *very same instance***.

Here's brief demonstration.

```sh
$obj = [PSCustomObject] @{
    'Example Header 1' = $null
    'Example Header 2' = $null
}

$array = @()
foreach ($ndx in 1..2) {
  # By working with the original $obj every time, you
  # keep modifying the same instance's property values.
  $obj.'Example Header 1' = "h1-$ndx"
  $obj.'Example Header 2' = "h2-$ndx"
  # Adding $obj to an array does NOT create a COPY of $obj
  # but stores a REFERENCE directly to $obj in the array
  # (similar to storing a pointer in unmanaged languages such as C++).
  $array += $obj
}

# Output the array.
$array
```

This yields the following:

```
Example Header 1 Example Header 2
---------------- ----------------
h1-2             h2-2
h1-2             h2-2
```

As you can see, only the *last* values assigned to `.Example Header 1` and `.Example Header 2` took effect, because both array elements reference the very same object.

**Martin's approach is the simplest way to solve this problem**: **create a *new instance* of the custom object *in every iteration*** (casting a hashtable literal to `[pscustomobject]`, as now shown in the question itself: `$array += [pscustomobject] @{ ... }`).

If you don't want to or cannot recreate your instances from scratch inside the loop, you have two basic choices:

- ***Clone* a *template custom object* in every loop iteration or simply use `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` object creation *inside the loop*, which implicitly creates a *new* instance every time**:

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58241314/45375)
- PSv5+ alternative: **Define a custom *class* and *instantiate it* in every loop iteration** - see below.

---

#### Class-based Solution

In PSv5+, a [custom class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes) allows for an **elegant solution** that also **performs better** than creating instances in-loop using literal syntax.

```sh
# Define a custom class that represents the rows of the
# output CSV.
# Note: [object] is being used here as the properties' type.
#       In real life, you'd use more specific types such as [string]
#       or [int].
class CsvRow {
  [object] ${Example Header 1}
  [object] ${Example Header 2}
}

$array = @()
foreach ($ndx in 1..2) {
  # Instantiate the custom class.
  $rowObj = [CsvRow]::new()
  # Set the values.
  $rowObj.'Example Header 1' = "h1-$ndx"
  $rowObj.'Example Header 2' = "h2-$ndx"
  # Add the instance to the array.
  $array += $rowObj
}

# Output the array.
$array
```

---

#### Performance Considerations

Two factors determine performance:

- How quickly the array is extended in each loop iteration:

  - **Extending an array element by element with `$array += ...` is very convenient, but is *slow and inefficient***, because a *new array*  must be created every time (arrays are fixed-size collections and cannot be directly extended).
  - For small iteration counts that may not matter, but the higher the number, the more performance will suffer, and at some point this approach becomes infeasible.
  - The next best solution is to use a `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]` instance to build the array instead - such lists are designed to be efficiently extended.
  - The **best and simplest solution, however, is to simply let *PowerShell* collect multiple outputs from a loop-like statement in an array, simply by assigning to a variable** - see below.
- How quickly the new object is instantiated in each loop iteration:

  - Instantiating an instance of the custom class is faster than creating an instance via the hashtable literal, but *only* if **`[CsvRow]::new()` is used for instantiation**; the functionally equivalent `New-Object CsvRow` is **much slower, due to involving a *cmdlet call***.

The following variant of the **custom-class solution uses *implicit* array creation to ensure *acceptable performance even with higher iteration counts***:

```sh
# Define the custom class.
class CsvRow {
  [object] ${Example Header 1}
  [object] ${Example Header 2}
}

# Determine the iteration count.
$count = 1000

# Loop and let PowerShell collect the outputs
# from all iterations implicitly in variable $array
[array] $array = foreach ($ndx in 1..$count) {
  # Instantiate the custom class.
  $rowObj = [CsvRow]::new()
  # Set the values.
  $rowObj.'Example Header 1' = "h1-$ndx"
  $rowObj.'Example Header 2' = "h2-$ndx"
  # Simply output the row object
  $rowObj
}

# Output the array.
$array
```

Note: The `[array]` type constraint is only needed if you need to ensure that `$ToWrite` is *always* an array; without it, if there happened to be just  a *single* loop iteration and therefore output object, `$ToWrite` would store that output object as-is, not wrapped in an array (this behavior is fundamental to PowerShell's pipeline).

Comment: It's interesting to see a use case for a class here. Why is the class more performant / preferrable than a PSCustomObject, e.g., ``$array = foreach ($ndx in 1...$count) { $rowObj = [PSCustomObject]{ example header 1 = "h1-$ndx"; example header 2 = "h2-$ndx"}; $rowObj } `` ? Or is it that better asked in a new question? Edit: Measure-Command gives me 16 ms for PSCustomObject and 10ms for the class using a count of 1000. It would be interesting to know more about this, or if there's a link I'll happily read it.

Comment: @Blaisem, in my benchmarks a custom class with per-property initialization is much faster than `[pscustomobject]`, and even using hashtable-based initialization with the custom class is faster, though not by as much. It's hard to explain it briefly, but `[pscustomobject]`s basically simulate arbitrary properties at runtime, which makes them both slow and more memory-hungry. If you have further questions, yes, please ask a new question.