# Add items into a collection array dynamically

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array

Okay.  Here's what I'm trying to do.  I'm basically trying to make a 2D array in powershell by importing stuff from AD and a SQL database.  I'm going to use the array to write, update, and delete rows in the database later in the script.  What I'm having a problem with, is getting everything into one variable.

When I run my code, it adds the same user over and over again into the desired array.  The very last item in the created to the $Table variable gets written over every single instance inside the $ToWrite.

I tried pausing after inputting all the variables into $Table, writing $Table to console, then writing $ToWrite to console.  The $Table changes correctly in every loop, but again, once it writes to $ToWrite it overwrites each instance.  I've tried multiple ways like .add(), PsCustomObject[], etc.  I'm just stuck now.

Here's my semi-functioning code:

```
$AllPOCs = Get-ADGroupMember 'ALL POC'
$POCs = @()

$Counter = 0

$AllPOCs | ForEach-Object {
    $Name = $AllPOCs[$Counter].SamAccountName

    $TestPOC = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CLIENT = '$Name'" -ServerInstance "SERVER\INSTANCE"

    if ($TestPOC -eq $null) {
        $POCs += Get-ADUser $Name -Properties * |
                 select -Property SamAccountName, GivenName, Surname, SID, EmailAddress
    }
    $Counter += 1
}

$ToWrite = @()
$Counter = 0
$SEQUENCE = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "Select TABLEFIELD FROM DATABASE WHERE NAME = 'FIELDID'" -ServerInstance "SERVER\INSTANCE"
$SEQUENCE = $SEQUENCE.RECNUM + 1
$Table = "" | select SEQUENCE, LASTUSER, GROUP, CLIENT, FNAME, NAME, EMAILID, USEDEPT, USELOCATION, CREATEDFROMSSD, DISPLAYCLIENTCOMMENTS, _INACTIVE_, WINUSERID, SELFSERVICEACCESS, SELFSERVICELICENSE, WIAENABLED, SID

#everything works correctly up to here

$POCs | ForEach-Object {
    $Table.SEQUENCE = $SEQUENCE
    $Table.LASTUSER = 'SYSTEMACCOUNT'
    $Table.GROUP = 1
    $Table.CLIENT = $POCs[$Counter].SamAccountName.ToUpper()
    $Table.FNAME = $POCs[$Counter].GivenName.ToString()
    $Table.Name = $POCs[$Counter].surname.ToString()
    $Table.EmailID = 'SMTP:{' + $POCs[$Counter].EmailAddress.ToString() + '}' + 
    $POCs[$Counter].EmailAddress.ToString()
    $Table.USEDEPT = 0
    $Table.USELOCATION = 0
    $Table.CREATEDFROMSSD = 0
    $Table.DISPLAYCLIENTCOMMENTS = 0
    $Table._INACTIVE_ = 0
    $Table.WINUSERID = '\DOMAIN' + $POCs[$Counter].SamAccountName.ToString()
    $Table.SELFSERVICEACCESS = 'TYPE'
    $Table.SELFSERVICELICENSE = 1
    $Table.WIAENABLED = 1
    $Table.SID = $POCs[$Counter].SID.ToString()

    $ToWrite += $Table #THIS DOESN'T WORK PROPERLY.
    $SEQUENCE += 1
    $Counter += 1
}
```

Output example:

```
SEQUENCE              : 1206
LASTUSER              : SYSTEMACCOUNT
GROUP                 : 1
CLIENT                : USERNAME
FNAME                 : FIRSTNAME
NAME                  : LASTNAME
EMAILID               : SMTP:{EMAIL}EMAIL
USEDEPT               : 0
USELOCATION           : 0
CREATEDFROMSSD        : 0
DISPLAYCLIENTCOMMENTS : 0
_INACTIVE_            : 0
WINUSERID             : DOMAIN\USERNAME
SELFSERVICEACCESS     : TYPE
SELFSERVICELICENSE    : 1
WIAENABLED            : 1
SID                   : S-1-Z-XX-CCCCCCCCCC-YYYYYYYYY-VVVVVVVVVV-125121

SEQUENCE              : 1206
LASTUSER              : SYSTEMACCOUNT
GROUP                 : 1
CLIENT                : USERNAME
FNAME                 : FIRSTNAME
NAME                  : LASTNAME
EMAILID               : SMTP:{EMAIL}EMAIL
USEDEPT               : 0
USELOCATION           : 0
CREATEDFROMSSD        : 0
DISPLAYCLIENTCOMMENTS : 0
_INACTIVE_            : 0
WINUSERID             : DOMAIN\USERNAME
SELFSERVICEACCESS     : TYPE
SELFSERVICELICENSE    : 1
WIAENABLED            : 1
SID                   : S-1-Z-XX-CCCCCCCCCC-YYYYYYYYY-VVVVVVVVVV-125121

SEQUENCE              : 1206
LASTUSER              : SYSTEMACCOUNT
GROUP                 : 1
CLIENT                : USERNAME
FNAME                 : FIRSTNAME
NAME                  : LASTNAME
EMAILID               : SMTP:{EMAIL}EMAIL
USEDEPT               : 0
USELOCATION           : 0
CREATEDFROMSSD        : 0
DISPLAYCLIENTCOMMENTS : 0
_INACTIVE_            : 0
WINUSERID             : DOMAIN\USERNAME
SELFSERVICEACCESS     : TYPE
SELFSERVICELICENSE    : 1
WIAENABLED            : 1
SID                   : S-1-Z-XX-CCCCCCCCCC-YYYYYYYYY-VVVVVVVVVV-125121
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need counters to find the current object in the loop, use $_ e.g. $AllPOCs | ForEach-Object { $Name = $_.SamAccountName ....etc

Answer (score 2):

**The problem is that you're updating the very same object, `$Table`, over and over, and adding references to that same object to the output array, `$ToWrite`** - all of whose elements therefore end up pointing to the one and only `$Table` object, whose property values at that point contain the ones that were assigned in the *last* iteration.

The problem is explained in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44115554/45375), which shows a possible solution using *custom classes*, available in PowerShell v5 and above.

A solution *without* custom classes requires you to ***clone* your custom `$Table` object in each iteration**:

```
# Create a new instance with the same properties:
$Table = $Table.psobject.Copy()
```

**Note**: This cloning technique only works as expected with *custom objects*, i.e., instances of `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]`, such as created by the `Select-Object` cmdlet and literal syntax `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }`

That said, **since you're assigning to *all* properties of your custom object in your loop, there is no benefit to creating a *template* object up front** - instead, simply **use literal custom-object creation syntax `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` (PSv3+) *inside your loop*, which implicitly creates a *new* instance in every iteration**.

---

Additionally, your solution can be streamlined, because **it is both simpler and more efficient to let PowerShell create arrays for you, simply by collecting the output from commands that output multiple objects in a variable**.

Here's a simplified example that puts it all together:

```
# Loop over the input and instantiate a new custom object
# in each iteration, then let PowerShell collect the results
# in array variable $ToWrite
[array] $ToWrite = 1..3 | ForEach-Object {
  # Instantiate and output a new custom object in each iteration.
  [pscustomobject] @{
    PropA = "ValueA-$_"
    PropB = "ValueB-$_"
  }
}

# Output the resulting array
$ToWrite
```

<sup>Note: The `[array]` type constraint is only needed if you need to ensure that `$ToWrite` is *always* an array; without it, if there happened to be just  a *single* loop iteration and therefore output object, `$ToWrite` would store that output object as-is, not wrapped in an array (this behavior is fundamental to PowerShell's pipeline).</sup>

The above yields the following, showing that distinct objects were created:

```
PropA    PropB
-----    -----
ValueA-1 ValueB-1
ValueA-2 ValueB-2
ValueA-3 ValueB-3
```

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate - big caveat here, I'm at home so can't test any of this but it should give you an idea:

```
$AllPOCs = Get-ADGroupMember 'ALL POC'

$Table = $AllPOCs | ForEach-Object {
    $Name = $_.SamAccountName
    $TestPOC = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CLIENT = '$Name'" -ServerInstance "SERVER\INSTANCE"

    If($TestPOC -eq $null) {
        $POC = get-aduser $Name -Properties * | select -Property SamAccountName, GivenName, Surname, SID, EmailAddress 
        $SEQUENCE = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "Select TABLEFIELD FROM DATABASE WHERE NAME = 'FIELDID'" -ServerInstance "SERVER\INSTANCE"
        $SEQUENCE = $SEQUENCE.RECNUM + 1
        [pscustomobject]@{SEQUENCE = $SEQUENCE;
                        LASTUSER = 'SYSTEMACCOUNT';
                        GROUP = 1;
                        CLIENT = $_.ToUpper();
                        FNAME = $_.GivenName.ToString();
                        Name = $_.surname.ToString();
                        EmailID = 'SMTP:{' + $_.EmailAddress.ToString() + '}' + $_.EmailAddress.ToString();
                        USEDEPT = 0;
                        USELOCATION = 0;
                        CREATEDFROMSSD = 0;
                        DISPLAYCLIENTCOMMENTS = 0;
                        _INACTIVE_ = 0;
                        WINUSERID = '\DOMAIN' + $_.SamAccountName.ToString();
                        SELFSERVICEACCESS = 'TYPE';
                        SELFSERVICELICENSE = 1;
                        WIAENABLED = 1;
                        SID = $_.SID.ToString()}
        $SEQUENCE += 1
    }
}
```

The above can also be simplified, but I've tried to keep it similar to your exisitng code

Comment: Indeed: Implicitly constructing a new custom-object instance in each iteration with literal syntax `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` is the best approach here (+1).